# IIS return 500 code while the code is return a 401

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, iis-7.5

I have a MVC Web API 2.0 Web service that is using an Authentication filter.
The code is pretty much following this blog.
https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

However recently the API started acting up. When incorrect credentials were provided it was returning a 500 instead of a 401. This code has been working for months and no change to the code has happened. So the first thing I did was to check out the solution running locally in IIS 10 and it worked fine. 
However the server runnig IIS 7.5 keep sending the wrong error code. I debugged the code in the server by attaching visual studio to the w3w.exe process and no exception was thrown. Actually I was able to see the code that returns 401 to execute correctly. Also set the debugger setting to catch any exception being trown and still didn't get any.

It seems to me like it is an IIS configuration problem, recently the server got a new certificate and changes were made to redirect http request to https. 
I looked in the logs files and saw the request being process with a 401

2017-02-02 05:39:09 W3SVC4 P4850772 69.174.252.42 GET /mobile_api/api/login - 443 - 73.204.143.208 HTTP/1.1 PostmanRuntime/3.0.9 - - "mysite.com" 401 0 0 261 313 109

So i can't pin point what configuration is causing that the client receives a 500 when it should have been a 401. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while but my issue has been fixed and thought i'll share it. The problem came from running a 4.5 .net version api as a web application inside a 2.0 .net version. I honestly do not know the details. But the migration for the parent side to .net 4.5 solved the issue with no change what so ever to API.